# How to change back to standard output console?

Tags: java, printstream

I tried to PrintStream to a text file for writing a bunch of output to a file.

But after the file is created, I was trying to switch back to the standard output just to continue on with other processes, but I have no idea about doing that switch. Seems like I have to setOut to the standard console, but how do I do that?

Below is the code that I used to output to a text file. Any ideas?

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fistr);
System.setOut(out);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What about saving the `System.out` `PrintStream` before setting it and then restore it? Or using the PrintStream associated with the file by it's reference `out` instead of `System.out`?

Comment: Thanks Diego. The first way works ! The second one I don't really know how to do that... For the first way, Joseph also gave a neat answer down below. Thank you both so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you save it before modifying it, so that you can go back?

```
PrintStream standard = System.out;
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fistr);
System.setOut(out);
/*
 some other stuff
*/
System.setOut(standard);
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much! I was able to finish the rest of the processes in standard output. This is actually my first post. Really glad to see such a neat response in such a short time. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Found it ! Just figured that out. haha.